# Titanium Tableview Android not showing rows

Tags: android, uitableview, titanium, cross-platform

I have developed a mobile application mostly on iOS and would now like to get everything working as it should in Android too. In my mobile application I have in the main screen a list of panels that is scrollable and consists of multiple panels. For this I used a TableView in iOS which is populated with rows and where each row has it's own layout. Such a row can contain a header with an image and text for example.
This is the code I use to create and populate the database in iOS:

```
var activityWall = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    width: '80%',
    top: '10px'
});

function populateActivityWall(append, receivedData) {
    var posts = [];


    if (!append)
        activityWall.setData([]);

    for(var id in receivedData) {
        var post = receivedData[id];
        var row = createPost(post);

        posts.push(row);
    }

    posts = posts.reverse();
    for(var i=0;i<posts.length; i++) {
        activityWall.appendRow(posts[i]);
    }
}


function createPost(post) {
    var row = {
        height: '88px',
        //selectedBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
    };

    var postView = Titanium.UI.createView({
        top: '18px',
        layout:'vertical',
        width: '100%',
        backgroundColor: Constants.Colors.white,
        borderRadius: 5
    });

    var header = Titanium.UI.createView({
        width: '100%',
        height: '70px',
        borderRadius: 5,
        borderWidth: '4px',
        borderColor: Constants.Colors.mediumGreen
    });

    var profilePic = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
        image: post.User.avatar,
        width: 'auto',
        height: '60px',
        left: '5%'
    });

    var nameDateLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
        text: post.User.name + " " + post.River.status.toLowerCase() + post.Object.name + "\n" + post.River.time_ago,
        left: calculateWidth('10%', 80),
        width: 'auto',
        height: '70px',
        font:{fontFamily:'Arial',fontSize:11} 
    });

    header.add(profilePic);
    header.add(nameDateLabel);

    postView.add(header);   
    row.add(postView);

    return row;
}
```

While this works perfectly on iOS, the code above does not show the table correctly in android. I already have checked multiple times, the data is received correctly and no specific warnings or errors are thrown. I even see that the table get's filled, as I see that the scrollbar shrinks and the rowseperators are visible. The rows themselves however are transparent and don't show anything.
Does anybody know what could be the issue? Thanks!

Comment: I have isolated the issue:
It turns out that the children of a tableviewrow in android just aren't shown. I started by adding only one row with a specific background color, which just showed up. However, when I add another view to that row, with another color it isn't shown.
I don't know yet if this is a problem that can be circumvented?

Comment: try to use tableViewRow (var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({ ... });)